# How to compile PHP using –with-password-argon2?

Tags: php, password-hash

I try to use PHP's `password_hash()` function with the `PASSWORD_ARGON2I`  algorithm, however, I get the following error message:

> **Warning**:  Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_ARGON2I - assumed 'PASSWORD_ARGON2I' (this will throw an Error in a future
> version of PHP) in **some-file.php** on line **181**
>
> **Warning**:  password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in **some-file.php** on line **192**
>
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null
> in some-file.php:232
> Stack trace:
> #0 some-file.php(232): PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 {main}
> thrown in **some-file.php** on line **232**

I followed [the official documentation of the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) word by word, but I still faced this error.

Then I made some research and I figured out that ["PHP should be compiled using `–with-password-argon2`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634750/travis-ci-php-7-2-dont-support-argon2i/47678023#comment82341219_47678023) ([where they refer to this file](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argon2_password_hash)).

I have no idea how to do this and I could not find any page which would guide me through the steps or provide me more info.

The hashing function works perfectly with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, but that is not what I need at the moment.

Comment: what php compilation has in common with your problem?

Comment: You'd need to give some information about your environment.   You download the PHP source and use configure/make with something like gcc to compile the C to an executable.  `--with-password-argon2` would be a configure option.  You may be in over your head if you've never compiled something before.

Comment: yes, I have never done compiling before as far as I know. So I do not really get this whole thing, that is why I asked for help. Do you have any suggestion where to start reading about it? @Devon

Comment: Try googling `compiling php from source`.  That'd be your best bet.  It's not complicated, but since you didn't provide any environment details, I can't tell you I recommend it.   If you installed PHP from system packages, you'll probably have a hard time making your own compiled version of PHP run properly with your web server.

Comment: I think it automatically installed with XAMPP 7.2.2.0, I hope this is the environment detail you were asking for @Devon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not know but OSX comes with pre-installed PHP. I had a very early version so I needed to upgrade it in order to make Argon2 algorithm work. When I checked my version by `php --version` in the command line, I got the following result:

> PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2017 20:30:32)
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

So I followed through this guide but I also had to install Argon2 library (which was not mentioned) and use `./configure —with-password-argon2`. So here are the steps which solved my problem based on [this guide](https://www.computersnyou.com/68/how-to-upgrade-php-in-mac-osx-compiling-from-source/):

1. Download the latest PHP source code f.e. [from here](https://downloads.php.net/%7Epollita/) (I used [this .GZ file](https://downloads.php.net/%7Epollita/php-7.2/php-7.2.7/php-7.2.7.tar.gz), but make some research whether there is a newer version or not)
2. Open the command line
3. Extract the GZ file and navigate to the extracted source code folder in the command line
4. You will need Homebrew, install it if you don't have it
5. Install the dependencies listed in [this guide](https://www.computersnyou.com/68/how-to-upgrade-php-in-mac-osx-compiling-from-source/) (run `brew install libjpeg`, `brew install pcre`, `brew install libxml2`, etc. in the command line)
6. Also install Argon2 library (this is not mentioned in the previous guide, you can use [this guide](https://brewinstall.org/install-argon2-on-mac-with-brew/))
7. Now run this in the command line (still same source code folder): `./configure —with-password-argon2`
8. run `make test` in the command line (time-consuming process, feel free to drink a beer meanwhile)
9. run `sudo make install` after
10. I also restarted my computer, not sure if it was necessary but it worked